# Cython - Standalone Binary

Tags: python, c, cython

I would like to know if when I "translate" Cython code into C the high level code generated in C references the Cython or it is standalone and can be compile into machine code without the .pyx file?

Comment: I have tried to use C with the python embedding module but when I compile the code the binary still references the Python code and if I delete .py file I cannot run the binary. Now, I am thinking to change strategy and use cython rather than embedding python in C. Ultimately, I am seeking a way to get a standalone binary from C that does not reference the python file.

Comment: No idea how Cython works, but normally there should be a function to pass the script as a string instead of the filename.

Comment: A binary from Cython does not depend on the .pyx file but it is unlikely to be truly standalone - it will not bundle any imports you use for example.

Comment: @DavidW Are you saing that if import for instance the modile nmpy in cython would not be converted in to C?

Comment: @Jonw3 Yes that is exactly what I am saying. The are other tools that may be suitable for what you want (PyInstaller, Nuitka, a few others). I don't know any of them well enough to recommend one